# What's the reason on "Memory is below 1MB, or missing a M/G at the end of the memory specification?"

Tags: linux, apache-spark

I'm building a spark cluster on my Linux operating system. but when I started it by using `./sbin/start-all.sh`, The following error occurred from the slave node.

```bash
Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Memory is below 1MB, or missing an M/G at the end of the memory specification?
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.WorkerArguments.checkWorkerMemory(WorkerArguments.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.WorkerArguments.<init>(WorkerArguments.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker$.main(Worker.scala:742)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.worker.Worker.main(Worker.scala)
```

I checked the environment configuration `cat /etc/profile` and reloaded it `source /etc/profile`.

The following is the content of spark-env.sh

```bash
export JAVA_HOME=/root/apps/jdk1.8.0_60
export SCALA_HOME=/root/apps/scala
export SPARK_MASTER_HOST=hdp-01
export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512
export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1
export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
```

But I found nothing wrong. What can I do to solve it?

Comment: here - `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512` - the default units are bytes. change this to `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2g` for example

Comment: ok,I will try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to study the configuration file and found that some configuration items are wrong.

1. SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY, set how much total memory workers have to give executors (e.g. 1000m, 2g).
2. SPARK_MASTER_OPTS, set config properties only for the master (e.g. "-Dx=y").
3. SPARK_WORKER_CORES, set the number of cores to use on this machine.
   ...

so I modify my configuration to:

```bash
    export SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=512M
    export SPARK_WORKER_CORES=2
    #export SPARK_WORKER_INSTANCES=1  # default 1
    #export SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077    # default 7077
```